# How to create an animated map in QGIS which cycles through column values

Tags: qgis, animation, timemanager

So I have a shapefile with 40 polygons(rows) and 30 columns where each column represent values from different time period.

I have created a map with graduated style by choosing values from one column but I want to do the same for every column. And if it's possible in QGIS, I need an animation or at least a slider to see differences through time.

Do I have to do that through web application or QGIS is capable of that (without writing a script). I am aware of time manager and mmqgis plugins but I believe they don't fit to my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late answer, but better than never...

First of all I think you need one graduated style that matches all of your columns, i.e. if an attribute value ranges from 0 to 30 at the beginning and from 20 to 50 some periods later your style should cover values from 0 to 50 to make things comparable (and otherwise my approach does not work).

I have created a small table structured as follows:

[image]

As you can see values range from 5 to 35, so I create a style ranging from 0 to 40 in intervalls of 5:

[image]

Now in the layer properties where you select the column an expression is needed, that selects a different column e.g. each second:

[image]

(klick on the ε right to the column combo box)

[image]

Here is the expression in plain text:

```
case
  when to_int(epoch(now()) / 1000) % 3 = 0 then "1970"
  when to_int(epoch(now()) / 1000) % 3 = 1 then "1990"
  when to_int(epoch(now()) / 1000) % 3 = 2 then "2010"
end
```

This counts the seconds (integer) since 1970, devides it by 3 and selects a column according to rest of the division. In other words, toggles the column every second. You may simply replace the `1000` for other time intervalls an the `3` according to your column count.

Note that the style does not refresh automatically, this can be achieved by a neat little python script that initializes a timer and calls a funtion that refreshes the layers every 1000 ms (you can directly type this in the editor of the python console):

[image]

```
def refreshAll():
    iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(refreshAll)
timer.start(1000)
```

If you start this script (press play button in the editor) your animation will immediatly start.

The result can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMgiwJlEOxs

Comment: Thanks @Jochen Schwarze. I couldn't find a solution at that time and I used the leaflet library to create an animated map. You can see it here [link](https://samaritakis.gr/webmaps/leaflet_animation_calendar.html). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no tool which does what you want in QGIS. Therefore, I would suggest to restructure the data. In most cases that should be much less work than developing a new tool.